# Is 'Viking' capitalised in this phrase?

Tags: capitalization

'Clothe someone in a viking costume.'

Comment: Look in your dictionary.  According to my dictionary, *Viking* is capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a non-proper definition of "viking" that is not capitalized.

But if you're referring to the Norse Vikings specifically, it is always capitalized.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Viking